# How can I embed a PDF viewer in a cross-platform C++ application?

Tags: c++, pdf, cross-platform

I need to embed a PDF viewer in my application. Is there any free software I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [poppler](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/poppler)

If you have Qt have a look at [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq27-poppler.html).

Answer (score 5):

You could use [libpopler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/), which is based on xpdf. There is a QT frontend, if you're already using that.

There is also ghostscript, which can render PDFs (and Postscript, of course). Generally, I'd prefer popler, as popler seems faster.

There is [MuPDF](http://ccxvii.net/mupdf/), which is also an Artifex product.

Popler is under the GPL version 2 (or later, I believe). The newest versions of Ghostscript are GPL 3, but you can get commercial licenses to it (or at least older versions) from [Artifex](http://www.artifex.com/). MuPDF is GPL as well, with commercial licenses available from Artifex.

Comment: this means i can't use it if the application is commercial?

Comment: To use poppler you need to get a commercial license (xpdf from foolabs).

Comment: @danio: you are **wrong** about poppler and commercial license from Foolabs. poppler is a freedesktop.org-hosted fork from XPDF, and is GPL only! Foolabs **does** provide commercial licenses, but only for their version of XPDF-based products, not for poppler.

Comment: @pipitas My implication was that one should use xpdf from foolabs instead of poppler. "You cannot use poppler commercially but you can instead get a commercial license for xpdf components (XPdfWidget/QT seems to be the current best match product) which are derived from the same source code from www.glyphandcog.com."

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of [development libraries on wikinfo](http://www.wikinfo.org/index.php/List_of_PDF_software#Development_libraries). The only free PDF viewing libraries currently on there ([MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/) and [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)) are GPL licensed so you cannot use them if you don't want to give the source code of your application away.

Comment: GPL license doesn't mean you can't sell your product. It just means you have to also give the source code for your product.

Comment: Link is dead, but Wikipedia has a page with less directed information, but still Poppler and MuPDF are there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_PDF_readers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PdfViewer](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php?content=149637) which is a lightweight PDF viewer that uses Qt/C++. It contains a `PdfView` widget which can be easily embedded in your application.